# Laravel Model primary key change error Illegal offset type

Tags: laravel, model

The illegal offset type shows this error when

```php
protected $primaryKey = ['user_id'];
public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `primaryKey` takes a string not `array` all you need is to change it to `string`

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```